Publish CLR C# Stored Procedure from Visual Studio 2017 with 'Assembly was not found in the SQL catalog' error
My project was created to read the database table and using the data from the table to call  a Web API and writing the the result of the Web API to another table. I am using System.Net.Http to call the Web API. Any suggestions for how to resolve the issue?
The exact error displayed below:
 Creating [MYProject]...
 (47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 1 
 Assembly 'system.net.http, version=4.2.0.0, culture=neutral, 
 publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' was not found in the SQL catalog.
 (47,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
 CREATE ASSEMBLY [FUSEAutomation]
 AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
 FROM 
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
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.


You'd be advised not do this anyway. If you want to read from the DB and upload via HTTP then you should use a more generalized tool outside of SQL Server for that. Such as a normal C# app, or even a Python or Powershell script.
